# Using user defined class having collections in webservices/jaxb

Tags: web-services, jaxb

I have a model class -

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "providerData")
public class ProviderData implements java.io.Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Map<String, String> customerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private List<DriverDataMap> driverDataMapList;
```

In the above class, DriverDataMap is another class as below-

```
public class DriverDataMap implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Map<String,String> driverFieldMap;
    private int key;
    private Map<String,String> drivingHistoryFieldMap;
```

Now the problem is I am able to unmarshall normal map in data model but not DriverDataMap.
Getting an exception as -

```
faultString: java.io.IOException: No serializer found for class
```

Please suggest some way to marshall/unmarshall the data model containing the user defined class references.

Comment: Which class is the exception complaining about?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan its DriverDataMap.